# Is there any way to increase visibility with a using declaration?

Tags: c++

The following code doesn't compile:

```
class C
{
    private:

        int m_x;

    protected:

        C(int t_x) : m_x(t_x) { }

};

class D : public C
{
    public:

        using C::C;

};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  D o(0);
}
```

The compiler's objection is that the constructor for C is declared `protected`, meaning that I can't access it from `main`.  In other words, it seems like the `using` declaration drags the original visibility of the identifier with it, despite the fact that it lives in the `public` block.

Two questions:

1. Why does this happen?  (Both in terms of the rules for how this works, and the rationale for making those rules).
2. Is there any way I can get around this without explicitly writing a constructor for `D`?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55927739/using-statement-and-protected-constructor) answers question 1.  Not sure if there is a general solution for question 2.

Comment: Why do you want to make the constructor protected? If it is to prevent construction of `C` objects then make the destructor for C pure virtual, which it should be anyway.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: Well, if nothing else it seems that *semantically* the accessibility of a member should tell you where it can be called from.  Also, I've heard that introducing the first virtual member to a class incurs some costs and should be avoided where possible, although that may be out of date nowadays.

Comment: If you have derivation, you almost always  need a base class destructor - most often, this will be pure virtual.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a subtle one. In C++, employing the `using` keyword on a base class constructor is called *inheriting constructors* and works differently than what a `using` keyword typically does. Specifically, note that

> If overload resolution selects an inherited constructor, it is accessible if it would be accessible when used to construct an object of the corresponding base class: *the accessibility of the using-declaration that introduced it is ignored.*

(Emphasis mine. [Source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration))

In other words, the fact that you've included the `using` declaration in a `public` section doesn't actually make those constructors public.

I believe that, in this case, you may have to define your own constructors to match the base type constructors.

Comment: Do you have any idea what the rationale for this is?

Comment: Sorry, no clue. This is news to me!

Comment: I think rationale is based on that `C` can have many overloaded constructors with different accessibility. Since with `using C::C;` you can't select only some of constructors this would level out accessibility of all constructors. This doesn't sound like a good idea, most people will expect unchanged accessibility of inheriting constructors.

Answer (score 0):

statement using C::C; is not about increasing visibility, but, about since c++11 
feature called inheriting constructors, making constructor of base class C invoking when derived D is constructed. You cant change access modifier of constructor that way. But, you can change access modifier, of any function by explicitly redeclaring it in a derived class with the different access modifier.

Comment: What do you mean by "explicitly redeclaring it in a derived class with the different access modifier"?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury simply, for example if you have protected function in base class with signature int func(int), you can redeclare it in derived class as public and do whatever you want in it(among others invoke base protected func), that way you basically change access modifier of member function in base class. Same is true if function is virtual in base etc.

Comment: Are you saying I can redeclare it without redefining it?  If so, how?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury, you need to define it, as well, of course. But from new definition you can call base implementation, and that way change acces modifier.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury also, if you want to use inherited implementation, you can use using directive in public section of derived class and that way change modifier w/o redefining it. Put in public section simply using C::func. And that feature is not applicable for constructors.